# Create a .war file that includes a jar-with-dependencies.jar for JNLP using Maven

Tags: java, maven, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a Maven project that builds a Swing client as a jar-with-dependencies.jar file.  I want to use Java Web Start to distribute this my.gui-0.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar file.  I've created a separate Maven project that builds a .war file with the JNLP artifacts for this purpose.  I need to include the my.gui-0.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar in this .war file.

I haven't been able to determine the Maven coordinates for the jar-with-dependencies.jar file.  If I use the Maven coordinates for the GUI project it puts the dependency .jar files for the GUI project in the WEB-INF/lib, which is not what I want.  I need to have the my.gui-0.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar file itself in the .war file.  (I suppose it could be in WEB-INF/lib.)

How do I tell Maven that the dependency is the jar-with-dependencies.jar file itself?

If there is another way besides the  mechanism to tell Maven to include the jar-with-dependencies.jar itself that would work too.  The jar-with-dependencies.jar has to be somewhere in the .war file I'm creating to support Java Web Start.

I know there is a Maven Webstart plugin, but [that looks like a nightmare](http://www.shaunabram.com/swing-webstart-maven/) so I'm just building a .war file myself with the necessary JNLP artifacts.

Comment: *"I suppose it could be in WEB-INF/lib"*  Not if it is intended for JWS Deployment.  Jars inside `WEB-INF/lib` are not accessible by a direct fetch (typing the URL in the browser address bar and hitting 'Enter') so they will not be available to applets or webstart apps.

Comment: The author of Maven Webstart Nightmare did get a working solution: http://www.shaunabram.com/swing-webstart-maven-example/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, what you want is the JAR file to be available to be *downloaded* by users of the WAR file.  Including the file in WEB-INF/lib as a standard dependency of the WAR project is not what you want.  What you most likely want is the JAR to be put in a different directory in the WAR (such as `/downloads`).

To achieve this in Maven, you can use the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin).

1: Use the dependency plugin to [copy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html) your JAR file to a temporary build directory.

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>my.group</groupId>
                  <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
                  <version>1.0</version>
                  <type>jar</type>
                  <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/webapp-downloads</outputDirectory>
                  <destFileName>myartifact.jar</destFileName>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

here we are copying your JAR file to the ${project.build.directory/webapp-downloads directory

2: configure the WAR plugin to include the resources generated by the dependency plugin.

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <resource>                  
              <directory>${project.build.directory/webapp-downloads</directory>
              <targetPath>downloads</targetPath>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

This will cause the JAR file to be bundled in you WAR under the `downloads` directory.  Users can then download it by going to /downloads/myartifact.jar to download it.

In the case of webstart, you would configure your JNLP with the appropriate path instead of having the user directly download the JAR.

Comment: Accepting your answer with my edits (I added the <classifier> to 1. in order to get my jar-with-dependencies).

Comment: Can the dependency plugin be used to also copy de .jnlp file. I'm strugling with copying my generated jnlp file from my jar project to the war.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the .jnlp file too, like in my case, you could use the unpack goal. This works because the webstart-maven-plugin can pack the jars and the jnlp file into a zip.

```
<execution>
    <id>unpack</id>
    <phase>process-resources</phase>
    <goals>
          <goal>unpack</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
         <artifactItem>
             <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>zip</type>
            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/webapp-downloads</outputDirectory>
        </artifactItem>
    </artifactItems>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```